# How can I kill a just started Java process in shell script?

Tags: java, linux, shell

I have this simple script where I execute a .jar file and I'd need its PID for killing it after the `sleep` command:

`java -jar test.jar &> output.txt & pid=$! sleep 10`

The problem is: the PID changes after the application gets fully launched, this pid I get in first place is not the same PID the application has after 10 seconds sleeping (I checked it using `ps`).

How can I track down the PID so that I can kill the fully launched application?

I've tried using `pstree -p $pid` but I get a long list of Java children processes and I thought there might be a better way to implement this other than getting every child process, extracting PID using grep and killing it, also because I'm not 100% sure this is working.

I found another solution using `jps` but I'd prefer use native linux commands for compatibility.

I don't necessarily need PID, using process name could be a way but I don't how to retrieve that either having only parent process' PID.

Comment: if `output.txt` is being used by java only, you may issue `fuser -k output.txt` :)

Comment: Why can't you just use `System.exit` in Java?

Comment: Never experienced pid change in the middle. This is very odd. did you write the whole statement in a single line?

Comment: If you don't have the original PID running anymore, but a different one, it means that the Java program (or perhaps the Java virtual machine) has started a new process (and then terminated).

Comment: Thank you all for your advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use process name, might run :

```
$ kill -9 $(ps aux | grep '[t]est.jar' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Options Details:

- `kill`: sends a kill signal `(SIGTERM 15: Termination)` to terminate any process gracefully.
- `kill -9`: sends a kill signal `(SIGTERM 9:Kill)` terminate any process immediately.
- `ps`:   listing all processes.
- `grep`: filtering, `[p]` prevent actual grep process from showing up in ps results.
- `awk`:  gives the second field of each line, which is PID. (ps output : $1:user, $2:pid ...)

Comment: Thank you for the useful advice (it's now working as expected) and thank you for the detailed explanation too!

Comment: You're welcome. please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways.

1. use system. Exit() inbuilt function.

or

2. redirect the pid number to a file and use later to kill the process.

Ex:-

```
java -jar test.jar &> output.txt & echo $! > pid-logs
cat pid-logs | xargs kill -9
```